# Laravel Eloquent - Relationship within a relationship when doing query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 tables which are related: projects, updates and update_items.

The user creates a project, then can create updates for that project but the update contains update items.

So, a project HAS MANY updates and an update HAS MANY update_items.

I currently have a relationship in the project model to get the updates:

```
public function updates()
    return $this->hasMany('App\Update');
}
```

And then in my controller:

```
$project = Project::with('updates')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

This works to pull in the updates and I get an array. But the table for updates is essentially like a pivot table containing just the id of the update and the relating project id.

What I need to know is how can I also pull in the update items that belong to the update?

I want to be able to do e.g:

```
@foreach ($project->updates as $update)
    @foreach ($update->item as $item)

        ECHO THROUGH THE UPDATE ITEMS

    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Can I do this in one query in my controller?

Or do I have to create another relationship in the UpdateItem model and then do in the controller:

```
 $project = Project::find($id);
 $updates = Project::with('updates_items')->where('project_id', $id)->all();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the dot notation for [nested eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)?

```
$project = Project::with('updates.update_items')->find($id);
```

Then, you can do this:

```
@foreach ($project->updates as $update)
    @foreach ($update->update_items as $item)

        ECHO THROUGH THE UPDATE ITEMS

    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Just a note though:

> Can I do this in one query in my controller?

Eager loading is a convenience. It doesn't run a single query. In this case, it will run 3 queries in order to build this hierarchical relationship.

Comment: This is why I love Laravel.